# *Help* Determining the run time of a program

Tags: runtime, time-complexity, big-o

Have to determine the run time of the following code.
For the following program fragment give a Big-O analysis of the running time.

I have tried to add numbers to the variable to see how long its going to take and how to simplify. Having difficulty with the i*i part. I understand that the second loop will run O(n) number of times, but struggle to understand the second. I know it will loop through (i^2) time giving it a run time of (i^2) but does that make the whole programs run time n + (n^2) or due to simplification due I just keep the high order number of (n^2) or am I completely wrong and the i's needed to e treated differently. I believe the deceleration of t, if statement, and t++ are O(1) and are neglect-able.

To summarize, I think the i's are confusing me on how I should treat them and how a (i^2) should be treated in overall run time. Since I know embedded for loops have a typical time of O(n^2).

```
int t = 0;                       //O(1)
for(int i=1; i <= n; i++)        //O(n)
   for(int j=1; j <= i*i; j++)   //O(i^2) 
      if(j % i == 0)             //O(1)
          t++;                   //O(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that typical nested for loops have a time of `O(N^2)`. They probably look something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        ...
```

Or some variation.

Since we are nesting them, we *multiply* their complexities. O(N) * O(N) = O(N^2).

Your function is a bit different since the inner loop is O(N^2) as you correctly identified, since we are squaring the value of n and then iterating that many times, and the outer loop is a standard O(N) loop.

O(N) * O(N^2) = O(N^3), which is the complexity of your overall function.

Comment: That's what I felt like but wasn't sure. Basing the second loop on i instead of n was a first for me and didn't know if it could be treated like another n or differently. Then I kept pondering if O(n) needed to be dropped since it was a low order term. But thanks for the help

Comment: the n in Big O notation refers to the input. Although the variable names are changed, the input to your overall function remains the same

Comment: Also you'd be correct about dropping the O(N) if they were independent loops. Since they are nested- you would have to multiply their complexities to get the overall complexity of that part of the function :) Glad to have helped